# Executing code before/after every MVC action from a 3rd party library

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am trying to execute a block of code before and after the execution of every Action on Controllers from a 3rd party library.

For technical reasons I can't use an HttpModule that executes at the beginning/ending of every page request - it needs to be far more granular and target the MVC actions themselves.

I know of ActionAttributes which can be created and added to Actions, but what can I do in the case where I cannot modify the original code?

Thank you

Comment: Wow, searched for this for ages.  5 mins after posting this I found the solution: http://weblogs.asp.net/gunnarpeipman/archive/2010/08/15/asp-net-mvc-3-global-action-filters.aspx

Comment: Requires MVC 3, which luckily I am running in my case.